# Pep8 Python3.3 Contradiction

Tags: coding-style, python-3.x, whitespace, pep8

Pep 8 has the following rules

> Blank Lines
>
> Separate top-level function and class definitions with two blank
>   lines.
>
> Method definitions inside a class are separated by a single blank
>   line.
>
> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of
>   related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of
>   related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).
>
> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
>
> Python accepts the control-L (i.e. ^L) form feed character as
>   whitespace; Many tools treat these characters as page separators, so
>   you may use them to separate pages of related sections of your file.
>   Note, some editors and web-based code viewers may not recognize
>   control-L as a form feed and will show another glyph in its place.

However, you can't have a *completely* blank line inside a class defintion

Example from my head:

```
class bunny:
    def spam(self):
        pass

    def eggs(self):
        pass

#a second example
class bunny2:
    def __init__(self):
        self._eggs = None

    def eggs(self):
        doc = "Spam and Eggs"

        def fget(self, value):
            return self._eggs

        def fset(self, value):
            self._eggs = value

        def fdel(self):
            del self._eggs

        return locals()
    eggs = property(**eggs())
```

The line between spam and eggs needs to be a blank line, however, that will result in a parse error of unexpected indentation. Is there another character that should go in that space? My assumption is just leave the spaces/tabs on the "blank" line because it is more readable.

In the second example nested defs need to have their previous lines indention maintained for the parse to work correctly.
What is the correct PEP 8 way to handle this? Blank line, blank line with white space, no line?

Comment: You've clearly got something wrong with your code. Mixed tabs and spaces, perhaps?

Comment: No not mixed spaces and tabs, it is all tabs. My question is based on those blank lines must maintain indentation with the block in which they are placed making them not "blank" (whitespace is still a character) My code runs fine these are just examples of the issue. Should those blank lines between defines contain spaces, or should they just be omitted. You can't have completely blank lines in the middle of a block, they must at least have the indentation level of the block in which they appear.

Comment: Are you dealing with the REPL? The language itself has no such restriction as you are speaking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in the REPL, you can't have entirely blank lines. But there is no reason for code entered in the REPL to strictly adhere to PEP 8, anyway. But inside a file, it is a good idea to follow PEP 8.

Comment: Ok perfect, that was what I was trying to figure out, I am working with a repl so You can't have the blank lines. That makes complete sense. Thanks!